Problem when creating a github repository via vscode
I was to trying to create a new repository directly via the vscode interface for a project in data science that i am beggining. The problem is that when creating the repository i accidentaly commited all the datasets which are .csv files over 100mb which github does not allow because of their sizes. Now the source control is stuck trying to publish a branch but it won't go through.
I tried git reset --hard HEAD~1 to undo the commits but it goes to back only for the first time I tried to commit and the .csv files are all there.
I have deleted the files from the local folder and added *.csv to .gitignore but it still keeps trying to publish the branch with the .csv files first because of the order of the commits. It takes forever to try to publish, it does not go through and now i cant commit anything because it is trying to publish this branch. Any ideas on how to fix?
Edit: For anyone viewing this and having the same problems, after running git reset --hard HEAD~1 I had to also undo the commit as resetting brought it back to the first commit state. So the only thing I had to do was undo the commit and i could start the process of creating the repository now without unneccessary files

Does this answer your question? How can I remove/delete a large file from the commit history in the Git repository?
